# Use of Stage picklist values Description

Tags: opportunity, standard-objects, ui

What is the use of Stage values description:

[image]

Is it displayed on user interface anywhere?

Comment: No, It doesn't appear the User UI, Only helptext comes at User UI, when you hover over yellow question mark icon.
It serve the same purpose, like all other metadata(field, object). Description is good, when someone looking at the field, so they can understood use of field or metadata.

Comment: thanks..do you know the max size of the description.is it 255 char?

Comment: Yes. 255 character

Answer (score 1):

No, It doesn't appear the User UI, Only help text given at fields comes at UI.
when you hover over yellow question mark icon.

Description at stage field of Opportunity serve the same purpose, like all other metadata description. Description is good, when someone looking at the field, so they can understood use of field or metadata.

Description has 255 character limit, which is standard text limit.